# Why is there a character 'e' while printing floating values

Tags: c++, class, random, struct, void

So, this is my problem, my "cene" is always not a real number, It always have a character 'e' in it... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream> //Vkljucitev knjiznice iostream
#include <string> //Vkljucitev knjiznice string
#include <stdlib.h> //Vkljucitev knjiznice stdlib.h
#include <windows.h> //Vkljucitev knjiznice windows.h

using namespace std; //Uporaba std::

//Razred za datum, kasneje vsiljen
class datum
{
    public:
    int leto;
    int mesec;
    int dan;
};

//Razred za racun
class racun
{
private:
    string naslov; //Rezervacija string, za ime racuna
    float cena[500]; // Skupna cena na računu
    int i; // Števec
public:
    datum izdaje; //datum izdaje za racun
   void nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi() //Podprogram za nastavitev, izracun in izpis racuna
    {
//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        cout<<"Podaj naslov racuna"<<endl;
        getline(cin,naslov);
        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        izdaje.dan = rand() % 30 + 1; //Dan
        izdaje.mesec = rand() % 12 + 1; //Mesec
        izdaje.leto = rand() % 30 + 1985; //Leto
        i = rand() % 99 + 1; // Koliko računov smo imeli.
        int produkti; //rezervacija za vse produkte
        produkti = i + rand() % 199 + 1; //Koliko produktov smo imeli
        cout<<"Produkti= "<<produkti<<endl;
        float produkt1[500]; //cena prvega produkta
        float produkt2[500]; //cena drugega produkta
        int a; //števec produktov
        a=0; //ki ga nastavimo na nič
//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

//Zanka za pridobitev dveh produktov
        do
            {
                produkt1[a] = rand() % 199 +1;
                produkt2[a] = rand() % 199 +1;
                a=a+1;
            }while(a!=produkti);
//Kateri produkt naj izpise
        int b; //kateri produkt bo izpisalo
        b = rand() % 199 +1;

//____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

//Zanka za pridobitev cene
        int h;
        h=0;
        do
            {
                cout<<"Cena: "<<cena[h]<<endl;
                cout<<"Produkt1: "<<produkt1[b]<<endl;
                cout<<"Produkt2: "<<produkt2[b]<<endl;
                cout<<"H: "<<h<<endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                cena[h]=produkt1[b] + produkt2[b];
                h=h+1;
            }while(h!= produkti);



//______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        //DDV
        float ddv = 1.12797374897; //DDV vrednost
        float cena2; //DDV cene
        float cenaddv; //cena z DDV-jem
        cena2=cena[h]/ddv; //izracun za DDV cene
        cenaddv=cena[h]+cena2; //izracun za ceno z DDV-jem
//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

//izpis
        cout<<naslov<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Dan: "<<izdaje.dan<<endl<<"Mesec: "<<izdaje.mesec<<endl<<"Leto: "<<izdaje.leto<<endl;
        cout<<"Produkt1 = "<<produkt1[b]<<"$"<<endl<<"Produkt2 = "<<produkt2[b]<<"$"<<endl;
        cout<<"Kupili ste: "<<produkti<<" produktov"<<endl; //izpis za produkte
        cout<<"Cena brez ddv: "<<cena[h]<<"$"<<endl<<"DDV: "<<cena2<<"$"<<endl<<"Cena z DDV: "<<cenaddv<<"$"<<endl;
    }
};

//Glavni program
int main()
{
    racun nekaj; //Rezervacija objekta
    nekaj.nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi(); //Izpis metode
    system("PAUSE"); //Zamrzni zaslon
    return 0; //Koncaj program
}
```

Can someone explain how I should proceed?
P.S. This program is in Slovenian.

**EDIT:**
I solved it... instead of doing this:

```
//Zanka za pridobitev cene
        int h;
        h=0;
        do
            {
                cout<<"Cena: "<<cena[h]<<endl;
                cout<<"Produkt1: "<<produkt1[b]<<endl;
                cout<<"Produkt2: "<<produkt2[b]<<endl;
                cout<<"H: "<<h<<endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                cena[h]=produkt1[b] + produkt2[b];
                h=h+1;
            }while(h!= produkti);
```

I did this:

```
cena = produkti*(produkt1[b]+produkt2[b]);
```

Comment: I don't see any `srand` call. Save yourself the trouble and use `<random>`.

Comment: A number like `2.67e+14` is just scientific notation, meaning `2.67 * 10^14`

Comment: But the cene[0]=-2.00124e+12 or something like that

Comment: @chris - using `<random>` doesn't change the need to seed the generator that you're using. Either way, if you don't seed the generator you get a default seed.

Comment: @user3029612: -2.00124e+12 is just -2.00124 * 10^12, same logic.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `cena` as a float.  The `e` that you see in the output, such as `1.035e2` is part of scientific notation.

If you need to output floating point numbers in a specific format, look up the operations defined in C++ standard headers `iostream` and `iomanip`  to control formatting.  This page may also be a good start:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

EDIT:  Also, looking at this loop:

```
        do
        {
            cout<<"Cena: "<<cena[h]<<endl;
            cout<<"Produkt1: "<<produkt1[b]<<endl;
            cout<<"Produkt2: "<<produkt2[b]<<endl;
            cout<<"H: "<<h<<endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            cena[h]=produkt1[b] + produkt2[b];
            h=h+1;
        }while(h!= produkti);
```

It appears this is the first piece of code that writes to `cena[]`, but it prints `cena[h]` before writing a new value to it.  So, that first `cout` will write out whatever uninitialized value was in `cena[]` before setting it to a new value.

This seems like incorrect logic.  Are you sure you want to print out the value before you've computed it?

Comment: @user3029612:  You probably want to move the `cout` and `system` statements after the line that says `cena[h] = produkt1[b] + produkt2[b];` then.  Incidentally, this will set `cena[h]` to the same value on each iteration, since you're indexing `produkt1` and `produkt2` by the a fixed index `b`.

Comment: Ah, I see the final problem.  You didn't want an array at all for `cena`, you wanted a total.  Had you wanted an array, the remaining error (which I did not catch) is that the code after the loop also referred to `cena[h]`, but it was reading the first element of `cena` you did not write to.